# How to combine TYPE and DIR command in windows cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

I have to translate a LINUX command into a Windows one. This is the command:

```
cat $(find folderName)/fileName
```

Searching online I found that:

1. `cat` can be translated with `type`
2. `find` can be translated with `dir`

So I tried to use something like this:

```
type @(dir folderName /s)/fileName
type < (dir folderName /s)/fileName
```

They are wrong, but I can't find any solution to combine them.
Can someone help me?

Comment: In general, you can't translate one language into another by just replacing the command names. `Cmd` uses `for /f` loops to capture the output of a command. `for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b /ad "folderName"') do type "%a\fileName"` might do what you want - if I understand your question correctly. Enter each command with the `/?` switch for detailed usage information.

Comment: However, what you really want to do is searching recursive in all subdirectories for a file with a specified name in a specified directory tree. For this purpose is neither __FIND__ nor __FINDSTR__ needed at all. There can be used __FOR__ with option `/R` or __DIR__ with option `/S` (and the options `/A-D /B`) or __WHERE__ with option `/R`. Each command has its advantages and disadvantages for finding a file in a directory tree. The usage help of all three commands can be read by running them with `/?` as argument.

Comment: __FOR__ and __DIR__ are internal commands of the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` while the command __WHERE__ is the external command `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe`. I recommend to use in a Windows batch file always the fully qualified file name of external Windows commands as that is faster (less file system accesses as no need to find the executable) and more safe as too many Windows users corrupt too often their `Path` environment variable because of not knowing what they are doing at all. A really good coded batch file works even on variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` not defined at all.

Comment: Some examples for usage in a batch file: `for /R "%SystemRoot%" %%I in ("about_Continue.help*.txt") do type "%%I"` - the file name in round brackets must contain `*` or `?` which can result in finding not only the correct file. __FOR__ ignores also files with hidden attribute set, but not the directories with hidden attribute. `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SystemRoot%\about_Continue.help.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do type "%%I"` - does not require a wildcard character and finds also the file `about_Continue.help.txt` even with hidden attribute set.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R "%SystemRoot%" "about_Continue.help.txt" 2^>nul') do type "%%I"` - that is the best solution on searching with wildcard patterns like `*.htm` as it applies the wildcard pattern only on real long file names and not also on the short 8.3 files names as __FOR__ and __DIR__ do which can result in matching files unexpected like files with file extension `.html`  which have in short 8.3 file name the file extension `.HTM` on searching for `*.htm`.

Comment: Thanks all! @Stephan advice did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I am confident that others will provide `FOR` loop solutions.

This is not difficult if you use PowerShell Core or Windows PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, Windows PowerShell was installed with it and is available.

While you might rightly say that this is more typing than needed in a bash/ksh script, it will run equally well on Linux, MacOS, and Windows without any modification. No 'translate' needed.

```
Get-Content -Path $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path '.' -Filter 'sheet1.xml' |
    Where-Object { $(Split-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) -eq 'worksheets' }).FullName
```

The amount of typing can be reduced by using aliases. While that is ok at an interactive shell, it is bad practice to encode aliases into script files.

```
gc $(gci -rec -file 'sheet1.xml'|?{$(Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) -eq 'worksheets' }).FullName
```

If you are desperate to run this from a `cmd` command prompt, the following could be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-Content -Path $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path '.' -Filter 'sheet1.xml' ^| ^
        Where-Object { $(Split-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) -eq 'worksheets' }).FullName

powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    gc $(gci -rec -file 'sheet1.xml'^|?{$(Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) -eq 'worksheets' }).FullName
```